# Add elements to list and return list in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'm trying to define a function that accepts a list of letters and returns the list with the last element removed. I'm fairly new to scheme so I'm not sure if this can be accomplished without creating a variable inside the function.
So far I've started with:

```
define funct (lambda (x) 
    (let (list '() )
     (if ( < (length x) 2 ) list (append ( list (car x))
```

Am I able to just slap on a recursive call like this:

```
(if ( < (length x) 2 ) list (append ( list (car x)) (set x (cdr x)) lambda (x))
```

Or is this wildly wrong?

Comment: Two words that Scheme programs very rarely contain are `length` and `set!`. Learn to live without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildly wrong, yes.

The reasoning would be as follows:

1. if the list is empty, or just has 1 element, return the empty list
2. otherwise, keep the first element and repeat with the rest of the list (recursion)

In code:

```
(define funct
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))
        '()
        (cons (car lst) (funct (cdr lst))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (funct '())
'()
> (funct '(a))
'()
> (funct '(a b))
'(a)
> (funct '(a b c))
'(a b)
> (funct '(a b c d))
'(a b c)
```